# How to solve the array in table?

Tags: html, twig

I have an array which looks something like this

```
0 => array:4 [▼
    "uniquenumber" => "123456"
    "name" => "Peter"
    "Type" => "Radio"
    "Class" => "A001"

1 => array:4 [▼
    "uniquenumber" => "123456"
    "name" => "Peter"
    "Type" => "Radio"
    "Class" => "A002"

2 => array:4 [▼
    "uniquenumber" => "2369"
    "name" => "Adi"
    "Type" => "FM"
    "Class" => "A003"

3=> array:4 [▼
    "uniquenumber" => "2363"
    "name" => "Peter"
    "Type" => "Radio"
    "Class" => ""
```

What I want to achieve in Twig (html) in table format. **Make sure the uniquenumber can contain more than one Class or sometimes Class can be Null as well**

```
Uniquenumber   name       Type     Class
123456         Peter      Radio   A001, A002
2369           Adi        FM      A003
2363           Peter      FM
```

My code for the table is like this but the main problem is with Class,  I am not able to get two class in one

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <th>Unique Number</th>
                    <th> Name</th>
                    <th> Type</th>
                    <th> Class</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody> 
                    <tr>
                         {% for products in product %}
                            <td>{{products.uniquenumber}}</td>
                            <td>{{products.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{products.Type}}</td>
                        <td> {{products.Class}} </td>
                        
                    </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far

Comment: Added the example as well.

Comment: You should move `{% for products in product %}` up one line.

Comment: @ruleboy21 The problem is not that, the problem is for class how to put two class in one <td> which are having same Class.

Comment: Which class? You mean an HTML `class` attribute or `products.Class`?

Comment: I meant products.Class

Comment: You should restructure your array in the controller or you want a twig-only solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered restructuring your array from yours example:

```
 0 => array:4 [▼
    "uniquenumber" => "123456"
    "name" => "Peter"
    "Type" => "Radio"
    "Class" => "A001"

1 => array:4 [▼
    "uniquenumber" => "123456"
    "name" => "Peter"
    "Type" => "Radio"
    "Class" => "A002"

2 => array:4 [▼
    "uniquenumber" => "2369"
    "name" => "Adi"
    "Type" => "FM"
    "Class" => "A003"

3=> array:4 [▼
    "uniquenumber" => "2363"
    "name" => "Peter"
    "Type" => "Radio"
    "Class" => ""
```

to this strucutre

```
0 => array:4 [▼
    "uniquenumber" => "123456"
    "name" => "Peter"
    "Type" => "Radio"
    "Class" => ["A001", "A002"]

1 => array:4 [▼
    "uniquenumber" => "2369"
    "name" => "Adi"
    "Type" => "FM"
    "Class" => "A003"

2 => array:4 [▼
    "uniquenumber" => "2363"
    "name" => "Peter"
    "Type" => "Radio"
    "Class" => ""
```

And with structure reformatted like this in twig you could simply join array items and display them like you described:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <th>Unique Number</th>
                    <th> Name</th>
                    <th> Type</th>
                    <th> Class</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody> 
                    {% for products in product %}
                       <tr>     
                            <td>{{products.uniquenumber}}</td>
                            <td>{{products.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{products.Type}}</td>
                            <td>{{products.Class|join(', ')}}</td>
                       </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```